# connect to mysql database via php using non-localhost user

Tags: php, mysql

I have a user called 'test'@'111.11.11.111' (for example).

When i call

```
mysql_connect('localhost', //mysql is hosted locally (as far as php is concerned)
              'test', //user is test
              'password');//test's password
```

it automatically tries to login 'test'@'localhost'. Trying `test@111.11.11.111` for username results in `test@111.11.11.111@localhost` to try logging in.

Can I tell php or mysql to log in 'test'@'111.11.11.111'?

**EDIT**: The mysql server is hosted on localhost (from php's perspective). The IP of server hosting the mysql database is something other than 111.11.11.111. The user is logging into the mysql server from IP address 111.11.11.111

Comment: is user name test@111.11.11.111 or something in this format? or user name is test and mysql is installed on the machine that has the IP 111.11.11.111? Can you clarify your question a little bit more, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think so, the point of setting where a user can connect from on the MySQL server (in this case '111.11.11.111') is for security. PHP can't override that security as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using 111.11.11.111 in place of 'localhost'? that should generate test@111.11.11.111

Comment: my understanding is that the first argument of mysql_connect is the location of the mysql server, not the location of the user...

Comment: That's correct. `localhost` is just a predefined string that will map to the IP of where your script is running. `test@111.11.11.111` means that It is trying to connect to 111.11.11.111 as user `test`. The location of the 'user' is irrelevant. The users have to be created on the same server that mysql is running.

Comment: so then the answer to my question is no, the user and the mysql server must exist at the same location...

Answer (score 1):

maybe I am misunderstanding the question, but why can't you just change connect statement to

```
mysql_connect('111.11.11.111','test','password');
```

??

Comment: my understanding is that the first argument of mysql_connect is the location of the mysql server, not the location of the user...

Comment: The DB user and the DB should be on the same server.